# Solving the parking lot fees

Tags: java, algorithm

I have a problem

Parking charge is 3$ per hour for the first 3 hours and for each extra hour you'll be charged 1$ and 24 hrs is 30$ but you can stay more than 24 hours.
I don't know how to solve the hours>24 like if car stays there for 37 hours, or more. I think that modulus has to be used for this, unfortunately I cant get this working.  any help ??

```
        if (hours >= 24) {
            price = 30;
            price += (hours - 3) % 1; //should the mod even go here?
        } else if (hours < 24 && hours > 3) {
            price = 9;
            price += (hours - 3) * 1;
        } else {
            price = hours * 3;
        }
        System.out.println("Hours: " + hours + " Price: " + price);
```

Comment: How does billing work over 24 hours? If they were there for 37 hours would it be $30 plus 17 hours @ $1 per hour?

Comment: Would it still just be $1 per hour after 24 hours?  If so then the "24" part seems irrelevant entirely.  The first three hours are one thing, all remaining hours are another thing.  In what way is the current code failing?

Comment: ye for example 25 hours stay should give price of 33$

Comment: @BlackHatSamurai exactly.  Note also that 3*$3+(24h-3h)*$1 = $30, so is there really anything special about the 24 hour mark?

Comment: If you had the total time spent parked in hours, dividing by 1 day will give you the total number of days, providing you take the floor of the result (because you want a whole number). If you mod by one day, you get the number of odd hours not counting whole days (if any). You need to use both of these

Comment: did you understand the answer?

Comment: Yes thank you. I could not get around it because of wrong approach. By now I have found other ways of doing it. Thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works:

```
if (hours >= 24) {
    price = (hours / 24)*30;
    int h = hours%24;
    int h4 = Math.min(h, 3)*2;
    price += h4 +((hours)%24);

} else if (hours < 24 && hours > 3) {
    price = 9;
    price += (hours - 3) * 1;
} else {
    price = hours * 3;
}
System.out.println("Hours: " + hours + " Price: " + price);
```

Comment: no after 24h its still 3$ for the first 3 hours and after 3 hours its 1$

Comment: But notice that after 3$*3hours is 30$, so that still works.

Comment: 24 hrs is 30$ but you can stay more than 24 hours. So 24h stay = 30$, then 25h stay = 33$, 26h stay=36$, 27h stay = 39$ then it costs additional 1$ per hour until it reaches 48h where price is 60$ and so on

Comment: Hours: 28 Price: 36.0 unfortunately it doesn't work as 28h should give 40$

Comment: @tomaszsvd try now

Answer (score 3):

based on your specification, it should be as easy as:

```
    price = Math.min(hours, 3) * 3 + Math.max(hours - 3, 0) * 1;
    System.out.println("Hours: " + hours + " Price: " + price);
```

update:

```
    price = (hours / 24) * 30 + Math.min(hours % 24, 3) * 3 + Math.max(hours % 24 - 3, 0) * 1;
```

Comment: This will not give correct price when hours > 24. After 24 hours, again first 3 hours are $3/hours and $1 for each extra hour!

Answer (score 1):

Modifying @bohuss's solution to fix the problem for more than 24hours:

```
private static int calculatePrice(final int hours) {
    // find number of days [where 1 day is 24 hours]
    final int days = hours / 24;
    // calculate price based on 1 day's fixed price as $30
    int price = 30 * days;
    // find remaining hours
    final int remainingHours = hours % 24;
    // calculate price for remaining hours and add to price for entire days.
    price += Math.min(remainingHours, 3) * 3 + Math.max(remainingHours - 3, 0) * 1;
    // return total price
    return price;
}
```

***Example Input/Output***

```
Hours: 0 Price: 0
Hours: 1 Price: 3
Hours: 2 Price: 6
Hours: 3 Price: 9
Hours: 4 Price: 10
Hours: 5 Price: 11
Hours: 6 Price: 12
...
Hours: 22 Price: 28
Hours: 23 Price: 29
Hours: 24 Price: 30
Hours: 25 Price: 33
Hours: 26 Price: 36
Hours: 27 Price: 39
Hours: 28 Price: 40
```

Comment: it looks like you are right :) the specification wasn't clear, but the example with calculatePrice(25)=33 cleared things up

Answer (score 0):

```
if(hours > 0) {
  if(hours > 3 && hours < 24) {
    price = 3 + hours;
  }
  if(hours >= 24) {
    price = 30;
  }
}
```

Note if the person parking still gets charged after 24 hours by $1 per hour then :

```
if(hours > 0) {
  if(hours > 3 && hours < 24) {
    price = 3 + hours;
  }
  if(hours >= 24) {
    price = 30 + hours - 24;
  }
}
```